# Generating jQ button from javascript for jQuery mobile pages to reduce repetition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a "home" button in the headers with this "standard" code at many places:

```
<a href="#home" 
    data-role="button" 
    data-iconpos="right"
    data-icon="home" 
   class="ui-btn-right">
   home</a>
```

**I want to render it from  a single piece of javascript code  since it appears many times in index.html** - to decrease code redundancy and for easier changes. (I want to  use jQuery so the cross browser functionality is ok)

The code bellow should :) work, what am I doing wrong ?

(I tried to solve it from different angles, I can write out text, put out other html etc. - but I can not tackle data-* and standard html attr together)

**THE CODE:**

*in index.html:*

```
<div  data-role="header">
    <a data-myButton="headerHome> </a>
</div>
```

*in main.js :*

```
$( function () {    
    // put home button into the headers:        
    $("a[data-mybutton = 'headerHome']").( function () {
        $(this).href = "#home";             
        $(this).data("role","button");
        $(this).data("iconpos","right");
        $(this).data("icon","home");
        $(this).class("ui-btn-right");      
    })
})
```

I call main.js as a last js file in my index.html

Comment: This is not valid `$("a[data-mybutton = 'headerHome']").( function () {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile it is not enough just to set the attributes. Correct page event needs to be used, also **.button(** function needs to be called to restyle the button correctly, like this:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $("a[data-mybutton = 'headerHome']")
        .attr("href","#home")
        .data("role","button")
        .data("iconpos","right")
        .data("icon","home")
        .attr("class","ui-btn-right");  
    $("a[data-mybutton = 'headerHome']").button();
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/heSKu/

Comment: Great ! thanks, I can see it working but in my life code it just rendres right even if I put the code straight into the body between <script></script> see:http://screencast.com/t/TkgRlkwMbR    it supposed to look like this: http://screencast.com/t/MKDopFONI  Where shall I put the code ?

Comment: Put it into HEAD into new js file. If possible never put your jQM code into BODY SCRIPT. Also take care that you use your proper page id in this line: $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){ . In my case page id is index, replace it with your page id. Or in case you want to do it in every page use it like this: $('[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){

Comment: I allways use separate js files, the problem was with  $('#index')

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid.

Perhaps you mean

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/B4zvx/) (Note that the data attributes are not shown in inspect element when set using .data)

```
$( function () {    
  $("a[data-mybutton = 'headerHome']")
    .attr("href","#home")
    .data("role","button")
    .data("iconpos","right")
    .data("icon","home")
    .attr("class","ui-btn-right");      
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I've tried to put it into <div> and use .text and .html jQ functions but no success. If you could give me a further hint I would appreciate otherwise I will return to this task latter